# Apache Ignite map string to enum

Tags: enums, ignite

I want to map a database VARCHAR value into an enum value in the model. I modified the field definition in QueryEntity and in JdbcTypeField such that the field type is my enum (instead of java.lang.String and String.class, respectively). The code executes but the value inserted in the DB is the ordinal corresponding to the enum value.

Is there a solution to this or is string to enum (and vice versa) conversion not supported?

Thanks!

Comment: ugh... sounds like a bug - I would submit an issue. The reason I believe it's a bug is that the Ordinal may change if additional fields are added to the enum at the beginning, for example, it will break! By saving the `.name()` or `.toString` there could be no ambiguity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to implement `JdbcTypesTransformer` (or extend existing `JdbcTypesDefaultTransformer`) to create your own mapping for specific column. The implementation can be provided in configuration via `CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory#transformer` property.